# How can i disable the automatic index creation in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to disable automatic index creation for an index but need to permit for another one. How can I disable the automatic index creation by elasticsearch for a particular index only?
I tried

```
action.auto_create_index: false
```

in elasticsearch.yml file,but it seems to disable all the automatic indexing for all.
Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"action.auto_create_index" is a bit complex beyond the true/false values. We can use patterns occuring in the index names to be identified and can specify whether it can be created automatically if it is not already existing.

An example would be

```
action.auto_create_index: -b*,+a*,-*
```

Here the index starting with "a" will be created automatically,but others starting with "b" are not allowed. -* indicates that other indices are not allowed and if you want you need to create them manually.

Also the order of the values also matters. For details,you can visit their documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation)

Comment: Do you mind explain how order matters? 
For example: if I put -* at the beginning like below: 
`action.auto_create_index: -*,-b*,+a*,`
Will -b* and +a* still work?
I didn't find it in doc.

Comment: Preference is given to preceding one. So -* in the beginning will prevent auto creation on all indices

Answer (score 4):

I received an error on elastic search node startup saying it couldn't create a ".monitoring" index.  Elastic search has some bookkeeping indices it uses that rely on auto-creation, so I needed to enable all indices that start with `.` If you define the environment variable on first start up then the following setting will allow any internal `.` indices to be created but will disable auto-creating any others:

```
 action.auto_create_index: "+.*"
```

Here the ".*" is not treated as a dotall regex so it will only match allowing creating indices that start with a literal "."

Comment: This is the only place I've seen someone clearly state that the matches are not regular expressions.  In the docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation) it doesn't describe the matching rules at all.
It appears to only have one special character - * - but I've not found that documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an index name pattern to specify whitelist/blacklist. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation) for more information.

> Automatic index creation can include a pattern based white/black list,
>   for example, set action.auto_create_index to +aaa*,-bbb*,+ccc*,-* (+
>   meaning allowed, and - meaning disallowed).