# Loading logs in one machine into elasticsearch located setup in another machine using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash

I have my logs and logstash running on the one EC2 machine (M1), so I read my logs placed on my local machine with this config:

```
input { 
    file{
        path => "/path/to/logs/in/M1"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
```

Now, we have elasticsearch running on a different EC2 machine (M2) and I need to transfer the logs from M1 to elasticsearch in M2 using logstash. I used the following output config:

```
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }

    elasticsearch {
            hosts => "http://<M2 ip address>:9200"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

When I run the config file, I get the following error:

```
04:18:57.640 [[main]>worker0] WARN  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - UNEXPECTED POOL ERROR {:e=>#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError: No Available connections>}
04:18:57.646 [[main]>worker0] ERROR logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Attempted to send a bulk request to elasticsearch, but no there are no living connections in the connection pool. Perhaps Elasticsearch is unreachable or down? {:error_message=>"No Available connections", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError", :will_retry_in_seconds=>2}
04:18:59.682 [[main]>worker0] WARN  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - UNEXPECTED POOL ERROR {:e=>#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError: No Available connections>}
04:18:59.686 [[main]>worker0] ERROR logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Attempted to send a bulk request to elasticsearch, but no there are no living connections in the connection pool. Perhaps Elasticsearch is unreachable or down? {:error_message=>"No Available connections", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError", :will_retry_in_seconds=>4}
04:19:01.109 [Ruby-0-Thread-17: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:188] WARN  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>#<URI::HTTP:0x1d08c988 URL:http://10.60.40.120:9200>, :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://10.60.40.120:9200][Manticore::ConnectTimeout] connect timed out"}
04:19:02.111 [Ruby-0-Thread-17: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:188] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:url=>#<URI::HTTP:0x55444fcf URL:http://10.60.40.120:9200>, :healthcheck_path=>"/"}
```

I am new to logstash. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

So I looked around in forumns and I got one solution which told me to update logstash output using the command:

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin update logstash-output-elasticsearch
```

I also updated the logstash config file to include username and password:

```
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }

    elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["<M2 ip address>"]
        user => 'username'
        password => 'changeme'
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        manage_template => false
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting a different error. Pleas help:

```
09:16:21.305 [[main]>worker0] WARN  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>404, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash-2017.04.17", :_type=>"Messagelog", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-04-17T10:06:11.348Z ip-10-60-40-201 No valid licenses found for COLL], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2017.04.17", "_type"=>"Messagelog", "_id"=>nil, "status"=>404, "error"=>{"type"=>"index_not_found_exception", "reason"=>"no such index and [action.auto_create_index] ([.security,.monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*]) doesn't match", "index_uuid"=>"_na_", "index"=>"logstash-2017.04.17"}}}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: On the machine M1, see if you can reach elasticsearch install on M2. Use this curl -XGET http://<M2 ip address>:9200. Also are M1 and M2 in different availability zones? Please can you share the configuration of your elasticsearch?

Comment: Can you also pls elaborate what information you require about elasticsearch configuration? I'm really new to this...

Comment: Ok, it looks like you have installed a secure elasticsearch. You should used this for the curl, curl -u username:password -XGET http://<M2 ip address>:9200.

Comment: M1 and M2 are in the same zone. I'm getting this as my response to the curl command:{
  "name" : "VvyphYg",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "EqXd4NbdRXi0kv_t9o1NWg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "780f8c4",
    "build_date" : "2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: Have you secured your elasticsearch?

Comment: yeah...its secured...i have also updated my post to include some new errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have disable auto creation of index on elasticsearch. By default elasticsearch supports auto creation of indexes.
Remove

```
action.auto_create_index: -b*,+a*,-*
```

(whatever the pattern) in your elasticsearch.yml and you will be good.

Furthermore if you want to accept auto creation of indexes starting with l used the pattern +l*. That is by adding

```
action.auto_create_index: +l*
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931092/how-can-i-disable-the-automatic-index-creation-in-elasticsearch) for additional informations.